# FFMpeg: how to split a video, process only parts and merge everything back together

Tags: ffmpeg, concatenation

I have a question. Do you think I could do the following with FFMpeg:

- split a long video in MP4 format into three parts
- alter only the first and the third part, reencode them into MP4
- finally, merge everything into a single video

and all this without unnecessary processing the middle part?

I have tested two approaches but in both cases there are issues with audio and video at points of merging. Additional info: I work in Windows 10. I currently export part 1 and 3 into AVI, then encode both files to MP4 before they are merged.

**Method 1 - no encoding**

I simply created a text file:

```
# inputs.txt
file `input1.mp4`
file `input2.mp4`
file `input3.mp4`
```

and run `ffmpeg -f concat -i inputs.txt -c copy output.mp4`. Unfortunately, the video freezes for a fraction of second with distorted audio at merging points, then continue.

**Method 2 - using filter complex**

```
> ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -i input2.mp4 -input3.mp4 ^
More? -filter_complex "[0:v][0:a][1:v][1:a][2:v][2:a] concat=n=3:v=1:a=1 [outv][outa]" ^
More? -map [outv] -map [outa] output.mp4
```

The video gets encoded but there are still problems at merge points, possibly less noticeable comparing to the method 1.

I wonder if there is anything else I could do to improve the output video, ideally without any issues.

Thanks